# Error with Ext.Msg in js-test-driver tests

Tags: javascript, extjs, js-test-driver

In my js-test-driver tests, I'm having an error from simply calling

```
Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'An error occurred while trying load parameters for action with id ' + actionId);
```

**Error Message:** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null

Note that `Ext.Msg.rendered` is `true` and that `Ext.Msg.el.dom.parentNode` is null if I stop execution just before the error.

This error does not happen if:

- The real app is running, only during tests.
- If I run a single test, only if I run multiple tests that end up calling `Ext.Msg.alert`

**Stack trace**

```
Ext.define.insertBefore (ext-all-debug.js:13281)
Ext.define.show (ext-all-debug.js:42064)
Ext.define.sync (ext-all-debug.js:82755)
Ext.define.syncShadow (ext-all-debug.js:33992)
Ext.define.onAfterFloatLayout (ext-all-debug.js:34002)
Ext.define.afterComponentLayout (ext-all-debug.js:34374)
Base.implement.callParent (ext-all-debug.js:4455)
Ext.define.afterComponentLayout (ext-all-debug.js:38639)
Ext.define.notifyOwner (ext-all-debug.js:38067)
Ext.define.callLayout (ext-all-debug.js:125114)
Ext.define.flushLayouts (ext-all-debug.js:125283)
Ext.define.runComplete (ext-all-debug.js:125769)
callOverrideParent (ext-all-debug.js:36)
Base.implement.callParent (ext-all-debug.js:4455)
Ext.override.runComplete (ext-all-debug.js:29905)
Ext.define.run (ext-all-debug.js:125750)
Ext.define.statics.flushLayouts (ext-all-debug.js:29913)
Ext.define.statics.updateLayout (ext-all-debug.js:29947)
Ext.define.updateLayout (ext-all-debug.js:31844)
Ext.define.onContentChange (ext-all-debug.js:36116)
Ext.define.updateLayout (ext-all-debug.js:31839)
Ext.define.onContentChange (ext-all-debug.js:36116)
Ext.define.updateLayout (ext-all-debug.js:31839)
Ext.define.setTitle (ext-all-debug.js:53058)
Ext.define.setTitle (ext-all-debug.js:55155)
Ext.define.reconfigure (ext-all-debug.js:90310)
Ext.define.show (ext-all-debug.js:90476)
Ext.define.alert (ext-all-debug.js:90600)
Ext.define.onInstanceRetrievalError (BaseWorkflowActionController.js:139)
(anonymous function) (ext-all-debug.js:2265)
Ext.apply.callback (ext-all-debug.js:7437)
Ext.define.Ext.apply.inheritableStatics.load (mock.js:38)
Ext.define.onDocumentClick (BaseWorkflowActionController.js:73)
(anonymous function) (VM6566:6)
Ext.apply.createListenerWrap.wrap (ext-all-debug.js:10786)
AsyncTestCase.test_unknown_error_displays_error_dialog (WorkflowSingleActionController.Test.js:87)
```

Any ideas of what could be going on? Or something to try?

This question was cross-posted to http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?288372-Error-calling-Ext.Msg.alert-from-js-test-driver-tests&p=1053744#post1053744

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that js-test-driver runs the following code which removes any content from the DOM at the end of each test.

```
var testRunnerPlugin =
      new jstestdriver.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin(Date, function() {
    jstestdriver.log(jstestdriver.jQuery('body')[0].innerHTML);
    jstestdriver.jQuery('body').children().remove();
    jstestdriver.jQuery(document).unbind();
    jstestdriver.jQuery(document).die();
}, runTestLoop);
```

Therefore, the global Ext.Msg which was rendered onto the body becomes orphaned and it fails when trying to sync the shadow.

The solution is not to use the global `Ext.Msg`, always instantiate a new `Ext.message.MessageBox` if you want your code to be testable in js-test-driver

Here's a test case that reproduces the exact same stack trace https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7i1